# Installing cython on windows 7, python 3.4.3 with pip

Tags: python-3.x, cython

I try to install cython on windows 7 64bit ( Python 3.4.3 ) via

```
pip install cython
```

and ends with the error message

```
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
```

Which I find kinda strange since I have visual studio community 2013 installed.
When I ask windows where vcvarsall.bat is it kindly answers me

```
C:\Users\me>where vcvarsall.bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

So it is in my path. Do I need a different visual studio version and with that a different version of vcvarsall.bat?

**Edit 1**
I downloaded the [VS2010 ISO](https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709969) SonicARG provided. Thank you.
Now cython acknowledges the compiler, but still fails to install.

```
pip install cython

  Running setup.py install for cython
    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-12j3y7gp\\cython\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(t
okenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-lgya62cy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-external
ly-managed --compile:
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    copying cython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\Cython
    copying Cython\CodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\Cython
    [Many lines of copying and creating]
    copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\cfuncs.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\Cython\Debugger\Tests
    running build_ext
    cythoning C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-12j3y7gp\cython\Cython\Plex\Scanners.py to C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-12j3y7gp\cython\Cython\Plex\Scanners.c
    building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-12j3y7gp\cython\setup.py", line 357, in <module>
        **setup_args
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-12j3y7gp\cython\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 164, in run
        _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-12j3y7gp\cython\setup.py", line 192, in build_extensions
        build_ext_orig.build_extensions(self)
      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-12j3y7gp\cython\Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py", line 172, in build_extensions
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 503, in build_extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc9_support.py", line 52, in query_vcvarsall
        return unpatched['query_vcvarsall'](version, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
    ValueError: ['path']

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-12j3y7gp\\cython\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(_
_file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-lgya62cy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" fa
iled with error code 1 in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-12j3y7gp\cython
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.4 is built against Microsoft's Visual Studio 2010; in order to build native modules **you must use the exact version**. You can just download the Express Edition to build them, the entire IDE is not necessary. You can fetch the [VS2010 ISO from here](https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709969), and install the C++ component, then try again.

*Note for future:* If you plan to upgrade Python to 3.5 (release date is September 13, 2015), the Visual Studio version will be 2015, so you can be ready if you have the save problem

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This compiler seems to be at least recognized by cython, but still fails. At some point during the installation it tries to >>running build_ext >>cythoning[...]\cython\Cython\Plex\Scanners.c. Then some stacktrace with the error ValueError: ['path']. These error messages are all so not helpful :/

Comment: Is the linked visual studio 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: For the first comment, try to paste the stacktrace onto the original post so we can find out what went wrong. For the second comment, I think is the universal ISO; to be honest I don't know it because the Visual Studio older downloads have been removed from the publicly visible download pages and only 2015 remains; the only way I could reach it was googling for it.

Comment: The new version of python and visual studio together work splendid. Thanks for the suggestion to wait.